# Cannot uninstall a plugin Eclipse Luna or reinstall it

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

Using the marketplace I installed a plugin (additional axis 2 tools) on a new Luna EE install.

I uninstalled it via the market place, and after a reboot it was still there. Tried this many times.

So I deleted the file manually from the plugins folder and the option was gone.

However, I want to reinstall it (I originally uninstalled it because the dialog kept containing the wrong information and stopping me from building aar file), but when I go to the marketplace it only gives me an option to 'uninstall'.

Ignoring how this is a bit crap, how do I remove this plugin so I can install it again?

I tried downloading the 1.6.2 jar direct from apache but it just gives me an error saying invalid jar repository.

(I know I can generate the service file/aar manually, but I want to do it this way).

thanks.

Comment: Possibly starting Eclipse with the '-clean' option will get it to clean up enough to recognize the plugin has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help, Instillation Details and try to remove it from installed software and then try to install it again.This works for me whenever I've to uninstall any software.